# Centre column contents in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have created a table using `tabularx` but I can't seem to centre the text within the columns. I have tried to use 'X' and 'c' (which works on tabular) but nothing seems to work. Can someone please advise? I am also unsure what `@{}*{3}` in the line `{\linewidth}{@{}*{3}{>{\arraybackslash}X}}` means.

Here's my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
\centering
  \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{3}{>{\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule\midrule[0.5pt]
 \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
\midrule
Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects & Access and account set up & 
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item Teast A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. \par
    Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. 
    \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
\end{enumerate} \\
\addlinespace
Evaluate the ease in learning to map & Learning how to map & Read tutorial \\
\addlinespace
Contribute data & Contributing data by classifying maps & 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
    \item Test A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. \par
     Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
     \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
 \end{enumerate} \\
\addlinespace
Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it & - & - \\
\bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\label{table:comparison of techniques}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I've also attached a picture of what I'd like to centre as an example.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for centering in `X` column type: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`

Comment: Another related question - if I wanted to move the 'contributing data by classifying maps' further down (to the centre of the box), how could I do this?

Comment: one problem to question, please :-). if you like to move only this text  in whole column, than  you can do this by use of `multirow` cell. if you like to vertical center text in all columns, than redefine `X` column as: `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`. your comment is not very clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

- for centering of cells' contents and at the same time preserve features of `X` columns, you can define new column type, for example

  `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`
- or in the case that in document is only one such column you can write as is done in mwe below
- beside centering in mwe below is improved appearance of the `enumerate` list. for this is added the package `enumerate` and `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % <--- added
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % <--- added
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,     % <--- added
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *         ,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
\label{table:comparison of techniques}
  \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                            X
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
                            X
                            @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
    \midrule
Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
    &   Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Teast A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

                    Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \end{enumerate}     \\
    \addlinespace
Evaluate the ease in learning to map
    &   Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
    \addlinespace
Contribute data
    &   Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \item Test A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

                Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \end{enumerate}     \\
    \addlinespace
Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
    & -- & --                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
```